# Reload all my MySQL tables

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Trying to set up phpMyAdmin I seem to have deleted all tables in my database: `allstudentsdb`

The database `allstudentsdb` is still there, but empty.

Good news: the tables were all saved in `/var/tmp/phpmyadmin.allstudentsdb.2020-06-26-09.36.mysql.UilgXQ`.

After installing I could not get phpMyAdmin to start, so I ran:

sudo dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin

I think that wiped out my tables.

How do I get my tables back?

---

EDIT: I fixed it! I always think these things are too difficult for me, but after searching and reading a MySQL tutorial, I manage to restore the tables as root, then logged in as my mysqluser, and they are all back! I have never done this before, so it's all new.

Sorry to have troubled you!

Answer (score 1):

To reinstall a mysql database:

(do this as root)

```
mysql>source /path/to/backup/mydb.sql
```

phpMyAdmin did tell me about a lot of errors, I think caused by None values in cells. I clicked 'Ignore all'

But my tables are back with the data!